# Unknown language in table after updating it from database

Tags: sql, netbeans, character-encoding

My database contains Russian language and Latvian language, when I try to fill my table with sql I get ???? in some fields, i can understand that program doesn't understand these languages, so my question is how can I fix it? Database is from Microsoft Excel

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
                        String filename = NamePath.getAbsolutePath();
                        String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=";
                        database+= filename.trim() + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true}"; 
                        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"","");

                        Statement s = con.createStatement();    
                        String sql ="SELECT [Course full name],Course,Action,Time FROM [Sheet1$] order by [Course full name]";//
                        s.executeQuery (sql);
                        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery( sql );                          
                        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Comment: can you please edit your question to say exactly which database you are using, provide the DDL for the table(s) and also the code you are using to insert into the database.

Comment: Moreover, for (say) Postgresql, we will need to know the setting of CLIENT_ENCODING and SERVER_ENCODING. This is generally a solvable problem, but because Unicode is more recent than the core of many database engines, it can be a little bit ugly.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus I have no idea what you said, I'm not that smart in programming please could you explain so i could understand.

Comment: Sure, sorry. Basically, the historical core of most databases is ASCII because not enough people (in the West) were thinking much about supporting Cyrillic alphabet, Chinese, Japanese, etc, back in the 1980-1990s. You probably know this already from nuisance of Windows codepages, if you use MS Windows. So, to take Postgres, you have to tell the server whether to interpret data as ASCII, Unicode, many other choices, _and_ when you retrieve data, your Java or whatever also has a choice of how to think of the data. Whatever DB you are using seems to have similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Found that it doesn't matter, now I can see that when program is done "clean and build" you run it and it understands everything, so it doesn't understand when in building mode.

Comment: Aaah! This is a problem with some Netbeans console! I would Google for that! Your DB is already correctly configured for Unicode.